# Como implementar Datatables + Vue.js adecuadamente

Tags: javascript, vue.js

mi problema es que al momento de integrar datatables.net a mi componente VUE, me aparece lo siguiente:(imagen de abajo), pero al momento de usar la busqueda se queda en blanco 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo en la parte del "< template>" 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi javascript es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: deberías poner el código como texto y no con imágenes, es más fácil para que podamos probar tu código

Comment: @blonfu sorry, es mi tercer post y la verdad aun no entiendo muy bien la manera correcta de hacer los post

Comment: Entonces deberías leer el [help] para enterder mejor cómo funciona el sitio. Aun así sigues sin poner el código en texto, solo tienes que [edit] la pregunta y poner el código en lugar de las imágenes

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de mucho encontré una posible respuesta,

solo basta agregar Update

```
 updated: function () {
   this.$nextTick(function () {
     $('#usuarios1').DataTable({
           'destroy'      :true,
           'stateSave'   : true,

        }).draw();

   })
 }
```

esto va antes de los metodos, y las consultas de axios tienen que estar en "let"

```
let data1 =axios.get("api/user").then((response)=>{ this.roles = response.data.roles});
```

para que vue pueda enviar la informacion a DataTables

Comment: Luego de casi 1 año y tu pregunta sigue con imágenes, si tienes chance de poner código en texto y darle formato, enhorabuena :D

Answer (score 0):

Intenta que en vez de llenar la tabla en el `template`, lo hagas por JS.

```
var data = [
    [
        "Yamile Ibarra xxxxxx",
        "yamixxxxxx@gmail.com",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    ],
    [
        "Jorge xxxxxxx",
        "jorge.x.xxxxxx@xxxxxx.xxx.xx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    ],
    ...
];

$('#usuarios1').DataTable( {
    data: data,
    ...
} );
```

Fuente: https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Arrays

Saludos!

Comment: temo que por java no podría ya que traigo los datos en un JASON y luego ya selecciono que es lo que quiero mostrar pero lo que he notado es que si uso el v-for, me aparecen fuera de la tabla pero si los pongo manualmente si aparecen dentro de la tabla

Comment: Eso es debido a que cuando se carga el DOM, DataTables carga todos los elementos que tenga tu tabla. Al añadirlos de forma dinamica lo que ocurre es que no le das chance de incializar los valores por defecto. Lo que tienes que hacer es buscar la forma de añadir los valores por JS o bién re-inicializar la tabla una vez obtengas los valores por Ajax. Saludos!

Comment: si es lo que estaba pensando, al parecer el ' this.$nextTick(' es lo que hace, vuelve a inicializar los valores del DOM, pero creo que ahi donde esta no debe de estar :S

Comment: Intenta colocarlo dentro del metodo [`watch`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property), en donde todo el rato estes "observando" a las variables `user` y `roles` cada que cambien su valor. Y simplemente agrega esa información a la datatable por medio del codigo que te dí en mi respuesta () `$('#usuarios1').DataTable( {data: data, ... } );`